# how to display multiple json result in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

I am working with weather api, having problem with displaying the multiple results ad using `$.each` function...

Can someone please tell if i am doing wrong,,,,
 Script&html

```
<div id="fj"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var teams;
            $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=33.5689&lon=72.6378&cnt=10", function (dataDD) {
                //do some thing with json  or assign global variable to incoming json.
                var tasks = $.parseJSON(dataDD.city);
                alert(tasks);
                //alert('empLoggedId');
                $.each(tasks, function (key, value) {
                    $("#fj").append(data.weather.description);

                });
            });
            });
    </script>
```

Any kind of help or reference will be appreciated...Thanks for your time

Comment: @PeterKA thanks for response, i am willing to load this multiple data into html which i got from api url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not parse already parsed as JSON data here `$.parseJSON(dataDD.city);`. And check the structure of the returned object.

Fixed example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/etumyan/pen/xGyRKJ?editors=101)

Comment: thanks for answer, i will surely accept after make it into work, +1 for effort

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use some HTML:

```
 $.each(tasks, function (key, value) {
                $("#fj").append(<p>data.weather.description</p><br />);

            });
```

Plus, I'm not sure what "data" is here.

Comment: thanks for answer, i will surely accept after make it into work, +1 for effort